# Knockout custom binding - displaying an image in bootstrap's popover?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the custom binding working, sort of:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/115/

The popover works but the content is a link, not the image itself.  How can I get the image to show up in the popover?

code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapPopover = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        var defaultOptions = {trigger: 'hover'};
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, options);
        $(element).popover(options);
    }
};
var viewModel = {
    sideOneTextContent: ko.observable('<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />')
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the 'html:true' option to the element binding. See [this update of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/116/)

```
<a class="image-content-saved" href="#" data-bind="bootstrapPopover: { content: sideOneTextContent(), html:true }">
    <img src="http://www.dailydesigninspiration.com/diverse/adv/publicis/Omax-Wide-Angle-Lenses.jpg" />
</a>
```